# change the specific cell value having common index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to change the value of particular cell of pandas Dataframe.  using `loc` i am finding all the column having the given index and then trying to change the given row and column value, but it is not reflecting in the original dataframe.

```
df.loc[df.index == 'Lactose intolerance ', 'abdominal pain'] = "yes"
```

result is :

Diagnosis

Lactose intolerance     yes

Lactose intolerance     yes

Name: abdominal pain, dtype: object

but when try to do for only one row it's not changing that cell value.

```
df.loc[df.index == 'Lactose intolerance ', 'abdominal pain'].iloc[0] = "no"
```

now the cell value is not changed. why is it happening so?

Comment: question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed)

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
df.iloc[row_index, col_index] = "no"
```

or

```
df.loc[row_index, 'Lactose intolerance] = "no"
```

Comment: I have index as  list value(Diagnosis) while creating dataframes hence i don't have unique indexes. So above won't solve the problem.

Comment: Yes it will, just use the second line of code and put the diagnosis string in "row_index" position

Comment: Diagnosis string is only 'Lactose intolerance' and that is multiple, if it was unique then there won't be any problem. Thanks.